# Promise.all wrapper with tuple type

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

i want to create a wrapper to promise.all with usage of tuple type. I was about to write something like this:

```
export function parallerRequest<TResponses extends any[]>(urls: string[]): Promise<TResponses> {
    return Promise.all<TResponses>(urls.map((url) => fetch(url)));
}
```

Expected behaviour should be that when Promise.all will be resolved, then returned data will be in shape of provided tuple. Any ideas how to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: What is not working? what error did you get ?

Comment: Type "Response" is not assignable to type "TResponses".

Answer (score 0):

Even if `Promise.all()` did a proper mapping over tuple types (which won't be [supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063) until at least TypeScript 3.1 is released), the problem is that there's no way for the compiler to verify that the result of mapping `fetch` over `urls` will result in a value of type `TResponses`.   All it knows is that it will be of type `Response[]`, which is wider than `TResponses`.  And therefore `Promise.all` returns a `Promise<Response[]>`.  If you want to tell the compiler not to worry about that, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
export function parallelRequest<TResponses extends Response[]>(
  urls: string[]
): Promise<TResponses> {
    return Promise.all(urls.map(x => fetch(x))) as Promise<TResponses>; // okay
}
```

This works.  But beware, the compiler warning is a good one.  Nothing in your signature for `parallelRequest()` will guarantee that, for example, `urls` is of the same length as `TResponses`, or that someone won't pass a subtype of `Response` for the elements of `TResponses`:

```
interface CustomResponse extends Response {
    prop: string;
}
parallelRequest<[Response, CustomResponse, Response]>(["/foo/bar", "/baz"]); // no error
```

So that's not really type safe.  I'm not sure what your use case is for specifying `TResponses` as opposed to just leaving it `Response[]`, but you should be careful.

Anyway hope that helps.  Good luck!